# Calculate and save a difference between columns with dates

Tags: python, timedelta

We have a dateframe, which has 2 i.a. 2 columns with dates. We need to calculate difference between them in days.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
date1 = datetime.strptime(payments['ts'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.strptime(payments['date'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
payments['delta'] = (date1 - date2).days
```

this gets the error: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'. What did I do wrong? Thank ye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import like this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
date1 = datetime.strptime(payments['ts'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.strptime(payments['date'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

[strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) belongs to the `datetime` class from `datetime` module as a class method.

Comment: Thank You. but I will have another error: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series. A column is Series, yes. How can I make another column that will have a difference between two other columns? thank ye

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633719/syntax-to-use-df-apply-with-datetime-strptime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu) can help maybe. Either way, the original issue from your question seems to be resolved, consider asking another question for your pandas issue. Mark the answer as accepted to close it. @Versteher